# pygtk error after update

Tags: python, pygtk

After manual updating python and python3 in Fedora 19 or Fedora 20 (x86_64) to versions 2.7.6 and 3.3.3 respectively I have got this error:

```
python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Dec 17 2013, 23:13:55) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import pygtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

Same happens if running python2 or python2.7.

After that I manually installed pygtk (from web site pygtk.org version 2.24, I hope it is the very version I need), but it haven't helped.

Comment: does a `import gtk` work? pygtk just provides the require function for a version check. So i never  import it anyway! Please provide sufficient version information. Which gtk, with which python version. On gtk 3 you do normally import over gi.repository if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Import gtk doesn't work too. I have added what version I installed -- seems to be gtk2.

Comment: I think the package in fedora is called `pygtk2`, make sure it's installed and up to date in your package manager.